# What is the purpose of an ampersand (&) in a PyQt4 string?

Tags: python, string, pyqt4

I'm going through some PyQt4 GUI tutorials and often see strings such as "&File" or "&Exit" in menus and the like.

My question is what is the purpose of the "&" symbol in this string? I can't see a difference when I miss it out. I've not come across it in other Python tutorials - is it somehow unique to PyQt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` causes PyQT to display an underscore under the letter that serves as a shortcut key for the menu item.